# how does htop gather system information in linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, htop

How does HTOP gather information like CPU consumption, memory consumption etc by every process and the whole system? I am not familiar with any operating system specific api (like socket api) that is provided by linux in order to gather those statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd point you to the `htop` sources, first.

Then, operating systems like Linux have a lot of interfaces to get those information. Some of these metrics are available via the classical `/proc` pseudo-filesystem, or via `/sys/`; others might be only available via `ioctl`s or specific system calls (e.g. `getgid`).